# pyserial: How is data being read?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to setup a simple program to read from COM port on my windows. It is connected to a CAN bus(USB interface). I set up the serial configs correctly and know that the port is open. However I am unable to understand the output read.

Here is what I have:

```
>>> ser.write('v')
1L
>>> ser.write('0x7f3')
5L
>>> ser.write('0x7e1300323f351')
15L
```

WHat are the 1L, 5L and 15L? Some length of bytes read? How can I see what data is really being received then?

I also tried *r= ser.read()* and then tried to display it by typing  *print r.decode("hex"*)

thanks

EDITED:

I have also used the RealTerm Software to perform sanity check. I have send a "V" and it returns a version string. However I tried the same from my python program( ser.write("V"). I see nothing when I print the response got from read(). Please help

Comment: The `1L`, `5L`, `15L` are the lengths of the written data. What happened when you tried `print r.decode("hex")`? Hint: `r=ser.read` does not call anything, you need parentheses for that.

Comment: I presume that this is using Python 2.x because of the `L` long specifier. It's the number of bytes that have been sent over the serial port. `ser.write('0x7f3')` sends the 5 ascii characters `0` `x` `7` `f` `3`, you might want to check your encodings if you wished to send hexadecimal.

Comment: ser.read was a typo! I did try ser.read() but then when I tried r.decode("hex") also I see nothing

Comment: Oh I presumed the 0x will send hexadecimal character :(

Comment: Is there a way to see how many bytes of data has actually been "read" by read() ??

Comment: `read()` probably returns a list of bytes read, so `len(r)` should be 1. https://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read Did you specify a timeout?